# Full Duplex Communication with RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, signalr

We have a messaging application that uses SignalR on a .NET Framework service to connect to clients of various kinds (native mobile + web in the browser). We're looking at potentially replacing SignalR with RabbitMQ to be able to facilitate communication back and forth between the service and various clients in a full duplex fashion. Would this be a viable usecase for RabbitMQ? In the RabbitMQ [tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) I didn't see a specific example that matched. the [RPC example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html) is close but it looks like the client initiates the connection, the server gets it, processes it and sends a reply. The connection is blocking from the server side. Is a usecase possible where both the client and the server are producers as well as consumers and they can asynchronously send/receive messages via the queues that they are subscribed to?

I'm not really sure where to ask this, if it's better asked on a different stack exchange please let me know.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this question?

Comment: We didn't end up using RabbitMQ for our usecase. From the research that I did it doesn't seem like it would have been the best option for our project (chat type messaging) because with how the RabbitMQ server works, creating and tearing down the exchanges that are responsible for message routing are expensive operations, so if you only wanted short lived sessions, that would be inefficient. We ended up just sticking with SignalR.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question.